# Jquery cookie plugin for popup message

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, cookies

I have a message that pops up when a user first visit my homepage. I'm trying to make that the message doesn't pop up if you have visited the page within the last 15 days. I'm thinking on using the [jquery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#readme) plugin to achieve that but not sure exactly how to use it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I'm using the colorbox plugin for my popup message, here is the code:

```
$(function () {
    $(window).bind('load',
    function (e) {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $.colorbox({ opacity: 0.3, href: "popupQualify.aspx" });
        }, /*timeout->*/2000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the cookie, show the popup if it is not present.  Then set the cookie with expiration of 15 days.

```
$(function () {
    if($.cookie('nopopup') === null)
    {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $.colorbox({opacity: 0.3, href: 'popupQualify.aspx'});
        }, 2000);
    }

    $.cookie('nopopup', 'true', {expires: 15});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function :

```
function getCookie(c_name){
            var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(';');
            for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
              {
              x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf('='));
              y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf('=')+1);
              x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
              if (x==c_name)
                {
                return unescape(y);
                }
              }
        };
        function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays){
            var exdate=new Date();
            exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
            var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? '' : '; expires='+exdate.toUTCString());
            document.cookie=c_name + '=' + c_value;
        };
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, it merely offers a second method of setting/getting cookies.

Comment: Thanks Majid, but what I'm trying to figure out is how do I setup jquery.cookie to activate the popup message only if you are a new visitor or if you are returning to my site after 15 days or more

Comment: exdays : expires date, set to 15 days !

Comment: @MajidShahmohammadi I don't think you're understanding.  The OP already has a cookie library--an API for setting and getting cookies--in mind. He wants to know how to use _it_ to accomplish the purpose detailed in his question.